DataStage Sequencer Stage doesn't continue the process after Nested Condition
I have a DataStage Sequence Job that needs to branch the process on the basis of which value is passed to a parameter.
I decided to add a Nested Condition Stage from which three links part. This is how the three paths are made:

Link1: Nested Condition Stage -> Job Activity1 -> Job Activity2 -> Sequencer Stage
Link2: Nested Condition Stage -> Sequencer Stage
Link3: Nested Condition Stage -> Job Activity3 -> Sequencer Stage

The Nested Condition Stage mentioned in the list is common to all the three branches. The Sequencer Stage is in common to the branches as well.
I need the Sequencer Stage because I need to connect the ultimate links of the three branches to the same activity, which closes the job.
The problem is that Link1 and Link3 correctly lead to a successful run, Link2 doesn't. The value of the parameter checked in the Nested Condition Stage for Link2 is correct. The only thought I have is that the Sequencer Stage a link coming from a Job Activity Stage. But there is no Job Activity I can put between the Nested Condition and the Sequencer. The proper definition of the process is as described in the list above.
Is there something I can do to solve this problem? Maybe I can substitute the Nested Condition with a Execute Command Stage, keep only Link1 and Link3, and using a command to skip the Job Activities in those links (maybe on the basis of the value of a certain parameter), but I don't know how and what to write as command.
Thanks in advance to anyone willing to help. Ask if you need more information.

The conceptional setup you describe should work. You could - for test purposes - add a job activity to your Link2 in order so see if the path gets activated or if the condition has some problem. Therefore you could build a simple test job (i.e. Row Generator and Peek) to check it out.

@MichaelTiefenbacher thank you for your reply. I ran the job again and it worked. I'm not sure what values I passed to the job in previous attempts, but it seems I didn't wrote them properly.
